# Breaking a UILabel into two lines at a certain spot

Tags: ios, ios7, uilabel

If I have a UILabel like so:

```
 UILabel *errorLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(30.0, 90.0, [self screenWidth] - 70.0, 50.0) ];
errorLabel.numberOfLines = 2.0;

errorLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Light" size:(12.0)];
errorLabel.text = @"Error: The email and/or password are incorrect. Try again.";
```

How do I split the text at password so it spits it out like this:

```
The email and/or password
are incorrect. Try again.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply insert a newline:

```
errorLabel.text = @"Error: The email and/or password\nare incorrect. Try again.";
```

You've already set the `numberOfLines` property, that's important as well.

Comment: That was simple, should have known that one. :o)